# Xamarin C#, Can I sort/order a JSON list that I gather via a httpclient?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can I somehow order the JSON I retrieve via a httprequest or is it only possible to do that in the backend?

I gather my data via this code: Can I add the line "?order=info1" (info1 is a value in my json) after my http-address?

```
    static public async Task<JObject> getInfo ()
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

        var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://localhost/information.php"); //can I add: "?order=info1" somehow? 

        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

        var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

        return jsonResult;

    }
```

My json looks like this:

```
    {
    status: "ok",
    records: [
     {
       info1: "test1",
       id: "78"
     },
     {
       info1: "test2",
       id: "79"
     },
     {
       info1: "test3",
       id: "80"
     }
    ]
  }
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
static public async Task<JObject> getInfo ()
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

        var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://localhost/information.php"); 

        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

        var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

        JArray sorted = new JArray(jsonResult["records"].OrderBy(obj => obj["info1"]));

        jsonResult["records"] = sorted;
        return jsonResult;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to sort the `records` array by doing this:

```
// sort by "info1" property
JArray sorted = new JArray(jsonResult["records"].OrderBy(obj => obj["info1"]));

jsonResult["records"] = sorted;
```

Comment: cannot find ".OrderBy"

Comment: @medvedo `using System.Linq`

Comment: does not seem to work. code runs smoothly but the info i gather gets into the app the same. the json remains the same. updating the post with the solution that does not make it quite work

Comment: check out my "updated code" in the post. is your code exactly like that?

Comment: In the log it works, but when I want to gather the data and put it out in a list it doesnt order as i want to

Comment: Can you convert your ids to ints instead and then sort? Or deserialize to a concrete class and then sort?

Comment: what specifically isn't working?  Which key are you trying to sort on?  Is the sample you posted (which is already sorted) an accurate sample of your real data?

Answer (score -1):

Is it difficult to use LINQ to object to sort an array ?

See https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQL-Ordering-Operators-050af19e